# Generate iterator object with tuples of varying size

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am trying to create a branch and bound algorithm, to do this I would like to create an iterator object which stores all possible combinations of a list of items of size 0 to n.

Take the following example to demonstrate:

```
import itertools as it

list_tmp = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

tmp_it = sum([list(map(list, it.combinations(list_tmp, i))) for i in range(2 + 1)], [])
```

tmp_it is a list of all possible combinations of size 0 to 2. This code works perfectly for small list sizes, but I need to act on a larger list and so would like to preserve 
the iterator characteristics of the it.combinations object (generate the combinations on the fly). e.g.

```
for iteration in it.combinations(list_tmp, 2):
    print(iteration)
```

Is there any method of doing this for combinations of multiple sizes? Rather than converting to a list and losing the characteristics of the iterator object.

Comment: never use `sum` on lists as it has quadratic complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [itertools.chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable), which lazily evaluates its argument. Something like this:

```
tmp_it = it.chain.from_iterable(it.combinations(list_tmp, i) for i in range(2+1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [chain](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) iterators:

```
>>> sizes = it.chain.from_iterable(it.combinations(list_tmp, i) for i in range(len(list_tmp)))
>>> for i in sizes:
...     print(i)
... 
()
('a',)
('b',)
('c',)
('d',)
('a', 'b')
('a', 'c')
('a', 'd')
('b', 'c')
('b', 'd')
('c', 'd')
('a', 'b', 'c')
('a', 'b', 'd')
('a', 'c', 'd')
('b', 'c', 'd')
```

Comment: Thanks, this was really simple - I probably should have been more thorough in my searches before posting. I think Koen got a working version code just before you edited yours unfortunately.